# Add extra, different label to each faceted plot's x-axis name on facet_wrap

Tags: r

I want to add a p-value label to each plot in a `facet_wrap` without renaming the top label of the faceted variable. I have set `scales="free"` so please take this into consideration.

I Was able to do it when plotting a discrete variable since I only need to provide the labels to `aes(x = labels)` on the `geom`. However, when faceting a density I need to provide the numerical variable which density I want `ggplot` to estimate.

Heres a minimum reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data frame
df <- tibble(Var = c("Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2", "Var2"), 
             Val = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2),
             Pvl = c("0.567", "0.049*", "0.078.", "0.003*", "0.567", "0.049*", "0.078.", "0.003*"))

# Plot
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = Val)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Var) + 
  labs(x = NULL)
```

Which results in:

[base plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu8Jg.jpg)

What I want it to return is:

[desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYDP1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't know how to set labels after facet, so I provide another option which uses `grid.arrange()` to put multiple ggplots together and set their labels respectively use `map2()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

df %>% split(.$Var) %>%
  map2(c("0.078.", "0.049*"),
    ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = Val)) +
        geom_density() + xlab(.y) +  # xlab(.y) is what you expect
        xlim(1, 4) + ylim(0, 0.8) +
        ggtitle(.x$Var) + theme_bw() +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))) %>%
  reduce(grid.arrange, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
 library(tidyverse)
      ggplot(df) + 
      geom_density(aes(x = Val)) + 
      facet_wrap(~Var,scales="free") + 
      labs(x="")+
      geom_text(data=data.frame(x=2.4, y=c(0.3,0.8), label=c("0.078.","0.049*"), 
                                Var=c("Var1","Var2")), 
                aes(x,y,label=label), inherit.aes=FALSE)+
      theme_bw()
            #You can change themes
            #y=0.8 and 0.3  to maintain plot
```

**The problem is you get the p values on top**
Plot:
[image]

Comment: I tried `geom_text` before, however, I need `scales = free` on the faceting so I can't set a fixed coordinate for the text. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Check the edit. The image is not the output. Depends on the scales="free" image. @AndersonNeisse how's that? You can examine the plots before placing the coordinates then adjust accordingly